# Re-writing without using unique construct in SQL

Tags: sql, unique, construct

Using the schemas member(memb_no, name, age), book(isbn, title, authors, publisher), and borrowed(memb_no, isbn, date), I have the following query. Only problem is I'm not supposed to use the unique construct. How can I re-write this without using the unique construct?

```
Select T.course_id 
From course as T 
Where unique (select R.course_id 
       From section as R 
       Where T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year = 2009);
```

Comment: The schema and SQL does not match..

Comment: Just to be clear, what is your query supposed to return?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already got other valid answers, but my preferred form would be:

```
Select T.course_id 
From course as T 
Where (Select Count(*)
       From section as R 
       Where T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year = 2009) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite your `unique` query as a subquery to join to `course`:

```
select t.course_id
from course as t
join(
    select course_id
    from section
    where year=2009
    group by course_id
    having count(1)=1
)r
on (t.course_id=r.course_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
Select T.course_id 
From course as T 
Where exists(select R.course_id 
       From section as R 
       Where T.course_id = R.course_id and R.year = 2009
       group by course_id having count(*)=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The UNIQUE construct returns *true* if the subquery is empty. Therefore, the correct equivalent to this query is (notice the <=):

```
SELECT
  T.course_id 
FROM
  course as T 
WHERE
  1 <= (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      section AS R
    WHERE
      T.course_id = R.course_id
      AND
      R.year = 2009
  );
```

P.S. This is an example in the textbook *Database System Concepts* (6th ed.). The example is given on p. 94 and the equivalent statement I mentioned is given on p. 95.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake on a book example.

See: https://www.db-book.com/db6/errata-dir/errata-part1.pdf (No.11)

A collect workaround for unique query:

```
SELECT T.course_id
FROM course as T
WHERE (
    SELECT count(R.course_id)
    FROM section as R
    WHERE T.course_id = R.course_id AND R.year = 2019
) <= 1;
```